# refer array of static constants(js) in node.js app.js file

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am having the below `app.js`  which serves the specific page.
I want to move `/v0/status.cgi` to the static constant(array) js file `AppConfig.js` and refer from there. But I am getting the below error.

How to add reference to an array available in `AppConfig.js` into `app.js` file?

**app.js**

```
app.get('/v0/status.cgi', function (req, res) {
 //return json
});

app.get(StaticConstants.Status, function (req, res) {
//return json
});

app.get(StaticConstants.Update, function (req, res) {
//return json
});
```

> ReferenceError: StaticConstants is not defined

**AppConf.js:**

**StaticConstants is an arrary as given below**

```
var StaticConstants = { 
   Status:'/v0/status.cgi',
   Update:'/v0/update.cgi'
};
```

Thanks

Comment: Your question is confusing. You have `StaticConstants.Status` in your `app.js`  but only `Index`  as property in you `AppConf.js`, do you miss the `Status` there. Beside that what is the problem with using the regular `module.exports = YourConfig`  in combination with the `var YourConfig = require('./YourConfig');` and where are `jquery` and `angularjs` related parts in the code?

Comment: Sorry . Edited ..please see the latest update

Answer (score 1):

You will use a regular *module.exports*  and *require*  pattern:

**AppConfig.js**

```
module.exports = {
  Status : '/v0/status.cgi'
};
```

**app.js**

```
var StaticConstants = require('./AppConfig');

app.get(StaticConstants.Status, function (req, res) {
   //return json
});
```

(assuming `AppConfig.js` and `app.js` are in the same directory)

Comment: Thanks niese . My StaticConstants.js file is having so many such constants and which are in an array . How to export all constants ?

Comment: @JavaUser you don't mention this in your question, and also not why you have a problem with that. What is the problem with adding them to the object you export?   `module.exports = {  Status : '/v0/status.cgi', AnotherConstant: '/foo', AndAnotherConstant: '/bar', SomethingElse: '/baz'};`

Comment: T.niese , can you give me the code to export an array variable present in AppConfig.js which is having multiple values and this should get accessible from app.js . I dont want each constant to be defined separately.

Comment: @JavaUser with so many questions you should know that with such a vague description of your problem it is not really possible to give an answer. Beside that it looks like this is a separate problem.

Answer (score -1):

I think, this is help full for you

**AppConfig.js**

```
module.exports = {
  Status :function(){
return '/v0/status.cgi'
}
};
```

**app.js**

```
var StaticConstants = require('./AppConfig');

app.get(StaticConstants.Status, function (req, res) {
   //return json
});
```

Comment: You should add explanations to your question. What is the purpose to pass a reference to a function as parameter for `path`? (imho express.js won't call it) and why do you export a function at all ? why  not just exporting the string, what is the advantage?